# How to do cross-validation in R using neuralnet?

Tags: r, deep-learning, cross-validation

I'm trying to build a predictive model, using the neuralnet package. First I'm spliting my dataset in training (80%) and test (20%). But ANN is such a powerful technique that my model easily overfits the training set and performs poorly on the external test set.
[Predicted vs True Value - Training is the right one and test set is the left one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1wsB.png)

Is there a way to do a cross-validation on the training set so that my model doesn't overfit the set? How may I do this with my own built in function?

Plus, are there any other approaches when dealing with deep learning? I've heard you can tweak the weights of the model in order to improve its quality on external data.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suggest to consider Bayesian Regularization for Feed-Forward Neural Networks: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/brnn/brnn.pdf

Comment: Anywhere I can read more about it other than the package manual? Thank you.

Comment: This is a good introduction: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/45539220_Bayesian_Regularization_of_Neural_Networks